# TinyMCE 4.x, change toolbar buttons states

Tags: javascript, initialization, toolbar, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE 4.x (the latest version), and I would like to set default values for the toolbar buttons on the 'init' event. For example:

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: 'selector-id',
   // more options...
   setup: function (ed) {
      ed.on('init', function () {
         // changes the 'font-size' input select
         var fontSizeButton = ed.getToolbarButtonByName('font-size');
         fontSizeButton.setValue('18pt');
         // changes the 'bold' button state
         var boldButton = ed.getToolbarButtonByName('bold');
         boldButton.setValue(true);
      }
   }
});
```

Of course, the "getToolbarButtonByName" function does not exist. I invented it to illustrate the idea. Is it possible to get a toolbar button by its name and then change its value?

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself. You can use the execCommand function:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.execCommand

This function performs some actions and also refreshes the toolbar buttons. My previous code would look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
   selector: 'selector-id',
   // more options...
   setup: function (ed) {
      ed.on('init', function () {
         // changes some font styles and refreshes the toolbar buttons
         ed.execCommand('FontName', false, 'courier new,courier');
         ed.execCommand('FontSize', false, '24pt');
         ed.execCommand('Bold');
      }
   }
});
```